# RXJS Emit true during one second, then false

Tags: rxjs

Is there any way to do basically this:

```
this.success = true;
setTimeout(() => {
    this.success = false;
}, 1000);
```

Using RXJS?

Comment: If you want it to tick back and forth, use the fact that [`interval`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) emits increasing numbers: `interval(1000).pipe(map((num) => num % 2)).subscribe((value) => this.success = !!value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. use the [`timer()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) function:

```
this.success = true;
timer(1000).subscribe(() => this.success = false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const success$ = timer(1000).pipe(map(_ => false), startWith(true));
success$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tpeyqk